# Excel : match two columns return value there are duplicate values in lookup list and table array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, lookup

I have a list of cities that I need to match to their city code. There are multiple instances(duplicates) in both columns. Please see image below.  Column D is the lookup values. I need to Match the cities in Column D to the Cities in Column A. When there is a match I need to return the city code in column B. My real lookup list (column d ) is lot longer, couple hundred rows . The city column I’m comparing it to (column a) has over a thousand rows.

I have tried vlookup but I’m not getting the right city code values. I understand with vlookup you can’t have duplicates. I can’t remove the duplicates here from the lookup list or the table arrays, I need to keep the lists as they are. A solution or general formula to point me in the right would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for any insight!

[image]

Comment: Please post the vlookup you tried, modified to the dataset you have shown.

Comment: In E2 the formula I have is =VLOOKUP(F2, $A:$B, 2, FALSE)

Comment: And what is that returning that is incorrect? realize it will only return the first matching record.

Comment: I’m getting N/A values when I can see the city in the lookup and  city name are the same.

Comment: Then check the data to ensure that there are no extra spaces or other non printable characters that would cause Excel to not see them as matches.

Comment: The data was checked for that, same issue still occurring. Thank you for helping troubleshoot.

Comment: This is also for exact values. I did try approximate as well, but it was not correct for all values.

Comment: I do not have anymore guesses.  The issue most likely is with the data.  There is something in the data that is causing the vlookup to not see it as match.  Try equating the values directly: `=F3=A2` and see if it returns true.  Does the vlookup work on your test data?

Comment: It does work on the test data, but I’ll look at my real data set again to see if there’s any issues preventing the matching. Not sure why it’s not working . Thank you for your assistance Scott .

Comment: Just one more question, the lookup values are in the left columns and the return in the right column?

Comment: *"In E2 the formula I have is =VLOOKUP(F2, $A:$B, 2, FALSE) "*; I know this is an older question but shouldn't F2 be D2? Also Scott was real sleepy suggesting `=F3=A2` as a test :p